# Untrusted data and XSS

Tags: xss, code-injection

I am reading up on XSS prevention and keep running into the phrase untrusted data. I understand what it means in terms of URL parameters, form fields, and cookies. However I do not understand what is meant by it in the context below.

For example, the [document I am reading](https://s://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) lists some examples like this:

```
<script>...NEVER PUT UNTRUSTED DATA HERE...></script>   directly in a script

 <!--...NEVER PUT UNTRUSTED DATA HERE...-->             inside an HTML comment

 <div ...NEVER PUT UNTRUSTED DATA HERE...=test />       in an attribute name

 <NEVER PUT UNTRUSTED DATA HERE... href="/test" />   in a tag name

 <style>...NEVER PUT UNTRUSTED DATA HERE...</style>   directly in CSS
```

What type of untrusted data are they talking about? I don't get it. I use script tags for local javascript files or links to CDN sites. I use comment tags to describe something in the code. When I put link addresses in an anchor tag I know where the link is going. Untrusted data in an attribute name? I've Googled these but have been unable to find anything that clears up my confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With untrusted data they mean data coming from the user or some other untrusted source which you cannot control.
Typical example is a url ending in: /index.php?name=joe
And then having that url parameter echoed into the page:
<!-- name is: <?php echo $_GET["name"] ?> -->